# How to stack rails helper methods in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, global-variables

I'd like to

```
@cart = Cart.find_by(id: session[:cart], :limit => 1)
```

but that throws out an error `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: carts.limit: SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts"  WHERE "carts"."id" = 1 AND "carts"."limit" = 1 LIMIT 1` so how can I use multiple methods on a single global variable? Version: `rails 4.0.1`

Comment: It's best to [_post a new question_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193625/189912) rather than editing your existing question to be dramatically different to the original. Doing so causes a lot of confusion...

Comment: downvoted, the question is not what the user wants to ask :S, refer to michael hampton's answer's comments

Answer (score 1):

It appears you mean to specify a limit of one record to be returned from `find_by`.

However, [`find_by` only returns one record anyway](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by), so this is not needed. Your `:limit` gets interpreted as a table column, which of course doesn't exist.

You can omit it entirely.

```
@cart = Cart.find_by(id: session[:cart])
```

Comment: Okay, bad example, here's the one I'm having issue right here: `@products = Product.all(:limit => 7, :created_at => :desc)`

Comment: That's a completely different question to this one that you've posted here.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that, I needed a similar thing with cart, but this is what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be querying by id, you can simply do:

```
ruby @cart = Card.find(session[:cart])
```

as `find` will do a `SELECT ... LIMIT 1` by the primary key.